# Using Blazor-component in ASP.NET Core MVC app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a solution consisting of projects:

1. ASP.NET Core MVC
2. Blazor Web Assembly

The second one is used for UI components used in an MVC application.
In the web application, I have a page at `host:port/myBooks/` where the user's books are presented through a for loop, each element has an `<a>` link to `myBooks/Details/Id`, where data about the book is extracted and redirects with view model to, for example, `myBooks/Details/39`.

A component from Blazor is connected on this page. Here is the working (in all other places of the application) code:

```
<div class="row">
    <component type="typeof(LiteraFlow.UI.Pages.ChaptersView)" render-mode="WebAssembly"></component>
    <script src="~/js/blazor.webassembly/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
</div>
```

But in this view, an error occurs in the console (f12):

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

And source of error:

> _framework/blazor.boot.json:1

The file is connected correctly. The component works in all other views - this is important. As I suspect, it's about the dynamic URL `myBooks/Details/39` which can take any number instead of 39. For some reason it doesn't work.

Has anyone encountered the problem of connecting the Blazor component file on views with a similar URL?

PS: connection

```
<script src="~/js/blazor.webassembly/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
```

in the `_Layount.cshtml` file leads to a huge list of problems that do not fit on the screen.

Why the strange way? Because a simple `src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"` doesn't work. The ASP.NET Core MVC application, although it has a link to the Blazor project, cannot access the `.js` file in this way. Therefore, a "client library" has been added (orange planet icon), in the path `wwwroot/js/`. Thus having a link.

I was trying to create new views in a web application, with the same url.

New test blazor projects and empty blazor components without logiс.
The error does not go away from this page. It works correctly on all others.

Comment: I have a new mvc app + new blazor wsam app, and test result like this. everything worked well, could you pls let us know more details about your apps? https://i.stack.imgur.com/MY8Lr.png